# Dearrangement of r objects out of n distinct objects

Tags: combinatorics

I know that de-arrangement of n objects is:

$$ D_{n} = n!\left(1 - \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} - \frac{1}{3!} + ... + (-1)^{n}\frac{1}{n!}\right) $$

but how to find de-arrangement of only r objects??
i read somewhere that $D_{n} = \binom{n}{n - r} D_{r}$

where $D_{r}$ = ways in which, $r$ things goes to wrong places.
$$ D_{r} = r!\left(1 - \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} - \frac{1}{3!} + ... + (-1)^{r}\frac{1}{r!}\right) $$

Question:

is this correct??

how to prove this using Inclusion-Exclusion??

$Edit:$

the above eq. is not using correct notation, which should be:

$D(n,r) = \binom{n}{n - r} D_{r}$

where, $D_{r}$ is de-arrangement of r objects out of r.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De-arrangement of $r$ objects mean that $n-r$ object are in correct places. These n-r objects can be chosen in $\binom{n}{n-r}$. And each of those selections have $D_r$ de-arrangements. Hence 
$$D(n,r)=\binom{n}{n-r}D_r$$
where $$D_{r} = r!\left(1 - \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} - \frac{1}{3!} + ... + (-1)^{r}\frac{1}{r!}\right)$$

Comment: your eq. is not same as mine.

Comment: Why do you say that?

Comment: i think your $D(n, r)$ is number of de-arrangement of r objects out of n, where as my $D{n}$ is number of de-arrangement of all.

Comment: You used same notation when referring to all n objects in dearrangement and when only r out n are in dearrangement. I just changed the notation you used in the question a bit so that things become a little clear. $D(n,r)$ means ways of having exactly r objects in dearrangement out of n.

Comment: ok, so it seems correct. this means in my eq. $D_{n} = \binom{n}{n - r} D_{r}$ is not correct.

Comment: it is correct, its just bad notation. See how you have defined $D_n$. The answer you write ie $ D_{n} = \binom{n}{n - r} D_{r}$ doesn't equal to the way you have defined $D_n$. The right hand of the result is correct.

Comment: actually, i got confused as it is given in a book like this. it should be $D(n, r)$

Comment: Don't dwell too much on notation, try to understand what it means.